# RTPDump File does not play correctly (tatering) when converted via Sox, but plays correctly in wireshark

Tags: wav, wireshark, sox

I am trying to Convert the `*.rtpdump` file, created by Wireshark into wav file by Sox.

In Wireshark the original file is played without any tatering sound in the audio file, but when I convert it to wav file via SOX (on Windows), there is continuous tatering sound throughout the clip and the actual voice remains in background.

I tried the u-law encoding, a-law  and others, the best it can get is with u-law, but it's also not so much audible. I tried the lowpass, gain, treble things but that also is not helping, changing channels, bit rate and other options make it worse.
Tried many things but tatering is not going

```
sox.exe -t raw  -r 8000 -e u-law  -c 1 66.rtpdump  -t  wav d:\out.wav -V
sox.exe -t raw  -r 8000 -e a-law  -c 1 66.rtpdump  -t  wav d:\out.wav -V
```

Comment: Same tatering sound is coming on ubuntu sox converting the rtpdump file.

Comment: One additional thing the wave file created has 50bytes before "data" tag, i dont know if this is releavant, but these are more than whats mentioned in wave file format documents.

Comment: I have also tried the same files on ubuntu, the tatering sound is reduced, but still their, tried different formats, amr, snd, etc. but tatering is still there.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/td$ sox -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law -c 1 36966.rtpdump -t f8 ./a.amr
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/td$ sox -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law -c 1 36966.rtpdump -t wavpcm ./a.amr
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/td$ sox -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law -c 1 36966.rtpdump -t wavpcm ./a.amr
ubuntu@ubuntu2004:~/td$ sox -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law -c 1 36966.rtpdump -t flac ./a.amr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first few bytes within each packet are causing this tatering sound.

I removed these bytes and the combined all the packets without these bytes to create a tatering free sound.